# Парсинг XML с русскими тегами

Tags: php, mysql, парсер, xml, xmlparser

Столкнулся с проблемой.
Исходный файл xml содержит только русские теги, собственно вопрос, как их можно парсить? Нужно залить такой файл в базу MySQL.
Например

```
<первый тэг>
<люди>
<чел>
<фио> </фио>
<инфа1></инфа1>
...
</чел>
<чел>
<фио></фио>
<тел></тел>
.. другие различные теги, которые могут быть не у всех
</чел>
..
</люди>
</первый тэг>
```

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема?

Comment: как мне обращаться к тэгам с русским названием ?

Comment: Всё ещё «и в чём проблема?» А как вы к английским обращаетесь?

Comment: Ну типо так $chel->fio

Comment: ЕМНИП `$chel->{'фио'}`

Comment: *Нужно залить такой файл в базу MySQL. Например* Вот не надо никаких "например". Выкладывай (a) XML-файл (2 записи достаточно); (b) CREATE TABLE таблицы, в которую надо положить данные; (c) финальное состояние таблицы.

Comment: У меня при разборе прекрасно работает $response = $client->Body->Регионы;

Comment: Если вас смущает кириллица, то можете заюзать какой-нибудь транслитиратор на входной xml, но, `$obj->{'кириллицей тег с пробелами'}`, будет работать ни чуть не хуже.